# forms authentication cookie value looks empty in firebug

Tags: asp.net, formsauthentication

I am having a lot of trouble getting a Forms Authentication Ticket and Cookie to work properly , for right now I am just wondering if it is normal for the cookie to appear to have no value in firebug when inspecting the value in FireFox and Chrome.  This doesn't seem right , after I go through this code the cookie appears , but is empty.  In this code sUserData is properly set.

I set it like this :

```
Dim sUserData As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("UserID").Value & "|" & 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("UserName").Value & "|" & 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("UserEmail").Value

Dim fat As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, _
    HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID"), DateTime.Now, _
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(6), True, sUserData, _
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, _
    FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)))
```

Comment: Is the behaviour also in Chrome ? Because I do use chrome and value do appear. I use chrome +F12 for watching cookie

Comment: even in Chrome F12 , it is appearing empty, and as you can see I skip the step Microsoft recommends to encrypt the ticket.

Comment: I was just making sure that there is supposed to be a value , if you want to answer I'll accept it

Comment: Could you first try for simple key value pair instead of FormAuthentication Ticket.

Comment: key value pair of what?  When debugging all the values are there on the Cookies.Add(..) line , but they don't get added to the browser

Comment: I just made a sample(but in C#) to confirm it again. I can see 2 cookie. ASP.NET_SessionId and .ASPXAUTH. Both contains some string value which are encrypted

Comment: ok , then something is wrong there , if I take out the encrypt  part I see it , I think I am missing some encrypt data in webconfig

Comment: I even added a simple cookie by  HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("Personal", "Name=Anand");
And it also appeared correctly

Comment: yea, all my other cookies show up fine , it is just this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, while using Chrome I could see the value of cookie. 
Let's try doing a simple check. Could you first try for simple key value pair instead of FormAuthentication Ticket.